# What kind of regularization can I use for CNN aside from L1/L2/Dropout?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, regularization

I am building a CNN to estimate a sequence of pitches existed in a song with this architecture:

```
model = Sequential()

kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None)

# conv 1
model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=2, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, bias_initializer='zeros', padding="same", 
                 activation='relu', input_shape=(image_width, image_height))) 
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# conv 2
model.add(Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# conv 3
model.add(Conv1D(filters=1024, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(51, activation='softmax', 
                              activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))

epochs = 300
batch_size = 50
weight_optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer = weight_optimizer , loss = "categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy', f1_m, precision_m, recall_m])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs, verbose = 1, validation_split=0.2)
```

This results to an overfitting model, where the train_accuracy at 97% max, but validation_accuracy only at 30% max. Loss is ranging from 2-5.

I try to use regularizer:

```
kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01), activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)
```

at every conv1d layer and dense layer, and resulting at a very high loss value, at the end of the epoch, it still produce a loss at about 200.

Is there any kind of regularizer I can use aside from L1/L2/Dropout/BatchNormalization in Python?